# Manage PHP globals in legacy app

Tags: php, global-variables, global

We have a legacy application which doesn't use any of our nice modern frameworks. One problem we're trying to deal with is pollution of the global namespace. As a contrived example, the entry point for the app is file1.php; it requires files, those files require other files...and many of them create variables:

**file1.php**

```
$color = 'purple';
require('file2.php');
require('file3.php');
```

**file2.php**

```
$sound = 'waterfall';
require('file4.php');
```

Eventually, after a few dozen of these files which make up this custom "framework", we get to our actual `page.php` where we can write our page-specific code for `page.html`. Problem is, `$color` and `$sound` were created way back in file1 and file2, so now we have to be extremely careful not to accidentally use these variables in our page-specific code.

Any ideas? Would maybe `unset`ing all of these variables immediately before `page.php` (in the primary "router" I guess) work?

Comment: edit the files?

Comment: This is where I hug and give proper loving to mass-file-search-and-replace ...

Comment: :) other than edit the files. That's definitely the long term plan, but am looking for a shorter-term stopgap.

Comment: Your title says remove global yet you state taking steps not to overwrite there variables. What exactly are you looking to solve here?

Comment: @nerdlyist not sure what you mean that we are "taking steps not to overwrite". Do we try to be very careful never to use `color` and `sound`? Sure. Do we want a better solution until sometime in the future we can get rid of these globals? Yes, and that's the question, how best to do that. If the only answer is "you'll have to completely rewrite the code" then so be it. In other languages e.g. javascript there are other stopgap measures, like wrap things in an anonymous function or iife.

Comment: @IncredibleHat sorry, not sure what you meant by your last comment exactly.

Comment: No worries. PhpStorm IDE actually shows us all the vars...and it's scary to say the least, we've got a lot of junk going on. We know we need to rewrite and clean this stuff up, but I'm hoping we could `unset` all of them or something as a temporary measure until we can rewrite.

Comment: Actually, YES IGNORE what I said. If you destroyed everything in $GLOBALS, you would kill all the $_POST $_GET $_SERVER items too lol. *ahem*, let me delete my comments for safety reasons.

Comment: If I remember correctly you need to declare global to use global variable in a function or method. So no problem in a function/method scope.

Comment: What is `$color` and `$sound` being used for? FYI your title does not ask your question well it is how to manage global variables not remove...

Comment: @nerdlyist changed the title. `color` and `sound` are used extensively in many many files, often conditionally, making it extremely hard to refactor

Comment: Are these for styles? Like fonts and stuff?

Comment: @nerdlyist no, this was a contrived example. They are for things vital to the operation of the app. User-related variables, things from the db, etc.

Comment: Can you give a more accurate example then?

Comment: @nerdlyist sure: `$userType = // get user type from the db (1 = customer, 2 = admin)`  Something like this in file1.php   This value is used throughout many pages of the legacy codebase. If we forget and use `$userType` in page-specific code, things can go awry.